# append cloned div, remove one class of div

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do:

When clicking any button of the class .plus,
clone the div #plusclone 
remove the buttons with the class .plus 
and append it to the div #eingabemsearch.

What my code does is to only clone .plus and append it. So pretty much the opposite.

```
 $(".plus").click(function(){
    var cloned = $('#plusclone').clone().find('.plus').remove();
    $("#eingabemsearch").append(cloned);
 });
```

It might be really stupid, but I've tried many differnet things and cant get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is due to the `find()` as that returns the `.plus` element, not the parent element that you cloned. To fix this you just need to re-arrange your logic slightly to keep the reference to the original clone. Also note that you need to remove the `id` from the clone to avoid duplicates. Try this:

```
$(".plus").click(function(){
  var $clone = $('#plusclone').clone().removeAttr('id');
  $clone.find('.plus').remove();
  $clone.appendTo("#eingabemsearch");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method so the reference holds on that element(the removed `.plus` element), to get back to the previous reference use [`end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end) method. The `id` attribute should be unique so remove it using [`removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr) method or update with a unique id using [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr) method.

```
 $(".plus").click(function(){
    var cloned = $('#plusclone').clone().removeAttr('id').find('.plus').remove().end();
    $("#eingabemsearch").append(cloned);
 });
```

or store the reference of cloned element in a variable and do the rest on the cached object.

```
 $(".plus").click(function(){
    var cloned = $('#plusclone').clone().removeAttr('id');
    cloned.find('.plus').remove();
    $("#eingabemsearch").append(cloned);
 });
```

Comment: There's no need for the `.end()` on your "or" option. It's also important to remove the ID (as Rory did).